# Why does a catch exception-declaration allow trailing parentheses?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I have come across some C++ code that looks like the following:

```
class exception {};

int main()
{
    try {
        throw exception();
    } catch (exception()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note the extra set of parentheses in `catch (exception())`. According to [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/Sorac5), this is compiled to the same object code as if it were written with `catch (exception &)`.

On what basis is the extra set of parentheses permitted, and what part of the standard allows this? As far as I was aware, a `catch` clause requires a type specifier, but `exception()` doesn't seem like a type specifier.

Comment: Looks like a function declaration to me. Same reason `exception(int)` works.

Comment: Seems something like a constructor invocation.

Comment: Try also `catch (int[5])`.

Comment: @Ayush You can't invoke a constructor, despite what the syntax makes you believe.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Exception handler declarations work like function declarations, in that array and function type parameters are adjusted to pointers. (That is, arrays and functions cannot be thrown or caught "by value".) Specifically, [except.handle]p2 says:

> A handler of type “array of `T`” or function type `T` is adjusted to be of type “pointer to `T`”.

So `catch (exception())` is identical to `catch (exception(*p)())`.

Comment: Ah right, so it's declaring an unnamed function with no arguments that returns a value of type `exception`.

Comment: Where is the exception caught?

Comment: @0x499602D2: In my example in the question, it's not. The catch clause is catching a totally different type of thing than is thrown.

Comment: @GregHewgill: No, it's not declaring a function. Rather, it's declaring a "parameter"-like variable with no name and whose type is "pointer to function". (In C++, you cannot declare functions as part of larger statements. I think in C you could do some pretty arcane stuff, but in C++ function declarations need to be independent statements.)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, sorry for my sloppy wording. Not an actual function of course, but a function pointer type.

Answer (score 1):

`exception()` is declaring a function. Per [except#nt:handler](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/except#nt:handler), an *exception-declaration* contains a *declarator*. A [function declaration](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct#:declarator,function) is a type of declarator. It's easy to see this because `exception(int)` also works just fine. Note that an *exception-declaration* happens to be exactly the same as a *parameter-declaration*, so it works exactly the same as declaring a function in a parameter.